# Set only last variable to file

Tags: bash, jq

In bash use jq to parse json.

```
  for currentActivation in ${ACTIVATION_ARRAY[@]}; do
      rulesResponse=$(curl -s -XGET "$RULES_REQUEST_URL_PREFIX&activation=$currentActivation&types=$rulesTypeKey&p=1&ps=1")
      typeRuleTotal=$(jq -r '.total' <<< "$rulesResponse")
      echo "current_rulesTypeKey = $rulesTypeKey, typeRuleTotal = $typeRuleTotal"
      jq --argjson totalArg "$typeRuleTotal" --arg currentType "$rulesTypeKey" '.rules.active[$currentType] = $totalArg ' <<<$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON >$FILE_REPORT_RULES
  done
```

And here output:

```
current_rulesTypeKey = CODE_SMELL, typeRuleTotal = 310
current_rulesTypeKey = SECURITY_HOTSPOT, typeRuleTotal = 1
current_rulesTypeKey = BUG, typeRuleTotal = 304
current_rulesTypeKey = VULNERABILITY, typeRuleTotal = 120
```

But on file **$FILE_REPORT_RULES** saved only last value = **120** :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "totalActive": 0,
    "totalInactive": 0,
    "active": {
      "BUG": 0,
      "VULNERABILITY": 120,
      "CODE_SMELL": 0,
      "SECURITY_HOTSPOT": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sequentially writing to the same file but always using the unaltered input `$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON`. This makes you see only the last change.

Instead of writing to the file on each iteration, you could save the changes to the variable and write to the file just once in the end:

```sh
for …; do
  …
  RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON="$(jq … <<<$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON)"
  …
done
cat <<<$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON >$FILE_REPORT_RULES
```

Or, if `$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON` needs to stay unaltered throughout the loop, use a temporary variable instead

```sh
temp="$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON"
for …; do
  …
  temp="$(jq … <<<$temp)"
  …
done
cat <<<$temp >$FILE_REPORT_RULES
```